# How do I fix matplotlib which is crashing my MacOS

Tags: python, matplotlib

I had to remove and reinstall my environment and since then matplotlib giving me major issues

I have had issues with matplotlib previously as the graphs won't show up so had to use 'tkagg' backend which worked absolutely fine. simple example below

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("tkagg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


filename = 'Data.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
print('done')
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

After I removed and reinstalled my environment (plus all libraries) a couple of days ago, my Mac OS crashes every time I run the same code and I am logged out of my Mac.

why do I need to explicitly need to use 'tkagg' in the very first place, and 2nd question why is it not working anymore?

its MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14999). It seems solutions are (1) Do not use a Mac, (2) Do not use tk (maybe qt5agg backenend instead). Also someone reported that downgrading python to 3.7.0 sorted this out.

Comment: thanks for the msg, well 'q5agg' didn't work, also 'tkagg' worked absolutely fine for over a year for so as I had no issues at all. which brings me to the python version. I have currently 3.7.5 and I think I had 3.7.0 previously. might have to downgrade, unless someone comes back with some other solution.  I have another Mac and python works fine on it, i.e. I   don't have to add 'tkagg' or anything.

Comment: Try to install pyqt, `qt5agg` is really the best backend to use.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that was a great advice ! works fine now, thanks a lot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest question for you. realised my console has really slowed down now compared to how it was previously. its is because of the qt5agg? scripts probably run faster I feel

Comment: I don't think the use of a different matplotlib backend should affect the console in general.

Comment: no, I definitely feel the difference. when I don't use qt5agg the console is much faster. strange there is mention of qt4 slowing down console. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000596224-python-console-with-iPython-very-slow-with-qt4-backend-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I am no expert for macs; but could it be due to [AppNap](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/AppNap.html) being active? (If that is the case there is a package [appnope](https://github.com/minrk/appnope) that could be used to deactivate it for python.)